# Android Spinner , set different value onItemselected

Tags: android, kotlin, widget

I want to set different values to a spinner when an item is selected, I set a list of country namse concatenate by country codes, on item selected event.
I want to set only the country code on view, but there is no method to set that value.

```
countryCodeSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,
    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onItemClick(
        parent: AdapterView<*>?,
        view: View?,
        position: Int,
        id: Long
    ) {

    }

    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
    }

    override fun onItemSelected(
        parent: AdapterView<*>?,
        view: View?,
        position: Int,
        id: Long
    ) {
        countryCode = codesList[position]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this code to get the view of the spinner and edit it after selecting :

```
override fun onItemSelected(
            parent: AdapterView<*>?,
            view: View?,
            position: Int,
            id: Long
        ) {

            if (position > 0) {
                val code = codesList[position]
                view!!.findViewById<TextView>(android.R.id.text1).text =
                    "+" + code.split("+")[1]
                countryCode = code
            }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following:

```
spinnerRangeForMap.onItemSelectedListener =
        object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

            }

            override fun onItemSelected(
                parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                view: View?,
                position: Int,
                id: Long
            ) {
                if (position != 0) {
                    //Your code
                }

            }

        }
```

and for item selected in spinner you can get as below:

```
 spinnerRangeForMap.selectedItem.toString()
```